# Why is my cookie not being sent? ReactJS front-end, Go back-end

Tags: reactjs, cookies, jwt, go-fiber

I am working on a personal finance application with a Go back-end (go-fiber framework) and ReactJS front-end.

My authentication method is to return a JWT as a cookie when a user signs in.

The front end sends a sign-in request using `fetch`, then follows up with another `fetch` to acquire user data. The `fetch` calls, as well as the server handler functions, can be found in the Appendix included at the end of this question.

When I test this out, I get a successful sign-in. A Set-Cookie header is returned and I see the cookie in the Response as I would expect it. However, the JWT is not being included as a header in the Request for user data. The handler returns `{"status": "unauthorized"}` as the parsed JWT is `nil`.

Why is the JWT not being included in the Request for user data?

Here is the Set-Cookie header, and a screenshot of all the Sign-In Response headers.
`jwt=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2NDY1MTczOTMsImlzcyI6IjE3In0.SDKnxjsVImuVOHw_hnsPX1ZhtS7-_6s8Cqk79SwniCY; expires=Sat, 05 Mar 2022 21:56:33 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax`

[Sign-In Response Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rqdvu.png)

Here is the JWT cookie being returned upon sign-in, and a screenshot of the cookie from Chrome Developer Tools.
`jwt    eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2NDY1MTczOTMsImlzcyI6IjE3In0.SDKnxjsVImuVOHw_hnsPX1ZhtS7-_6s8Cqk79SwniCY    localhost   /   2022-03-05T21:56:33.000Z    195 ✓       Lax         Medium`

[Sign-In Response Cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQasy.png)

I do not see anything in the "Cookies" section of the Application tab. However, I read somewhere else that I should not expect to see any cookies with `httpOnly` set to true here.

[Application Cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPqp5.png)

I am expecting to see a header called "Cookies" in the user data Request. But I am only seeing these:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:9000
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36
```

[User Data Request Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znaaT.png)

Would greatly appreciate any nudges or help. Here are links to the GitHub pages for the front-end and back-end code in case it helps explain the problem:

[ReactJS Front-End](https://github.com/Jack-Timothy/personal-finance-frontend/tree/dev)

[Go-Fiber Back-End](https://github.com/Jack-Timothy/personal-finance-backend/tree/dev)

**APPENDIX**

Sign-In Request `fetch`:

```
        fetch('http://localhost:9000/signIn', requestOptions)
            .then(res => {
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    res.json()
                        .then(
                            (result) => {
                                if (result.status && result.status === "success") {
                                    this.props.onRouteChange('home');
                                } else {
                                    // TO DO: display failure message on UI
                                    console.log('Failed to sign in');
                                }
                            },
                            (error) => {
                                this.setState({
                                    isLoaded: true,
                                    error
                                });
                            }
                        );
                } else {
                    console.log('Error signing in');
                    res.json()
                        .then(
                            (result) => {
                                console.log(result);
                            },
                            (error) => {
                                console.log('Error reading JSON of response with status !== 200');
                                console.log(error);
                            }
                        );
                }
            });
```

Sign-In Handler Function:

```
func handleSignIn(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    // unmarshal received sign in data into User struct
    var signIn User
    if err := c.BodyParser(&signIn); err != nil {
        err = fmt.Errorf("failed to process HTTP request body to /signIn: %w", err)
        log.Println("Error:", err)
        c.Status(fiber.StatusBadRequest)
        return err
    }

    // look for the identified user in the users database
    usr, err := getUserByUsername(signIn.Username)
    if err != nil && err == sql.ErrNoRows {
        log.Println("Error: user", signIn.Username, "attempted to sign in but not found in users database")
        c.Status(fiber.StatusBadRequest)
        return fmt.Errorf("invalid username/password combination")
    }
    if err != nil {
        err = fmt.Errorf("failed to query database for user %s: %w", signIn.Username, err)
        log.Println("Error:", err)
        c.Status(fiber.StatusInternalServerError)
        return err
    }

    // hash the given password for comparison with the recorded password
    err = bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(usr.Password), []byte(signIn.Password))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("CompareHashAndPassword returned error during sign in attempt:", err)
        c.Status(fiber.StatusBadRequest)
        return fmt.Errorf("invalid username/password combination")
    }

    // declare claims for the JWT that will be sent back
    token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256, jwt.StandardClaims{
        Issuer:    strconv.Itoa(int(usr.Id)),
        ExpiresAt: time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 24).Unix(), // 1 day
    })
    if token == nil {
        err = fmt.Errorf("failed to instantiate JWT")
        log.Println("Error:", err)
        c.Status(fiber.StatusInternalServerError)
        return err
    }

    // encrypt the JWT with the private key
    tokenString, err := token.SignedString([]byte(jwtPrivateKey))
    if err != nil {
        err = fmt.Errorf("failed to encrypt JWT: %w", err)
        log.Println("Error:", err)
        c.Status(fiber.StatusInternalServerError)
        return err
    }

    c.Cookie(&fiber.Cookie{
        Name:     "jwt",
        Value:    tokenString,
        Expires:  time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 24),
        HTTPOnly: true,
    })

    // send response
    return c.JSON(fiber.Map{
        "status": "success",
    })
}
```

User Data Request Fetch:

```
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("http://localhost:9000/getExpenses")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    if (result.status !== null && result.status === "unauthorized") {
                        console.log('Failed authorization when requesting expenses!');
                    } else if (result.expenses === null) {
                        console.log('Response did not contain expenses map');
                    } else {
                        this.setState({
                            isLoaded: true,
                            expenses: result.expenses
                        });
                    }
                },
                (error) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        error
                    });
                }
            );
    }
```

User Data Request Handler:

```
func handleGetExpenses(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    // parse JWT from HTTP cookie
    token, err := parseCookie(c)
    if err != nil {
        c.Status(fiber.StatusUnauthorized)
        return c.JSON(fiber.Map{
            "status": "unauthorized",
        })
    }

    // check which user is getting their expenses
    claims := token.Claims.(*jwt.StandardClaims)
    userId, err := strconv.ParseInt(claims.Issuer, 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        err = fmt.Errorf("invalid Issuer field in JWT")
        log.Println("Error:", err)
        c.Status(fiber.StatusUnauthorized)
        return err
    }

    // get all expenses from the database
    expenses, err := getAllExpenses(userId)
    if err != nil {
        err = fmt.Errorf("failed to get expenses from expense table: %w", err)
        log.Println("Error:", err)
        c.Status(fiber.StatusInternalServerError)
        return err
    }

    // send response
    return c.JSON(fiber.Map{
        "expenses": expenses,
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `fetch` doesn't use cookies. You can make `fetch` use cookies like this:

```js
fetch(url, {
  credentials: "same-origin",
}).then(responseHandler).catch(errorHandler);
```

You can check the docs for more details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#parameters

Comment: That completely solved my problem. Didn't realize how many configuration options there were for `fetch`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad it worked for you 